# How to connect to microsoft access from html

Tags: asp.net, web

I am php developer, but just today I was approached and asked to design a site that would use Microsoft Access as the database, the problem is I do not know how to do this, the company policy does not allow mysql, or php to run on their server, so am stuck and I feel bad when someone tells me that the only way is via ASP.NET, which I am not familiar with.

I really would love anybody to help, 
I would appreciate all help,

Comment: I know my question might be a little too vague, I beg for your pardon

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a nice and easy step-by-step guide on how to connect to Access Databases in ASP.Net

Just check the link below. I hope it helps.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821765

Comment: I checked it out, wow, I do not do ASP.NET nor VisualBasic, thanks anyway

Comment: If you can't develop using PHP or mySQL then what other languages can you use at your company that you're familiar with? I'm sure there's a way to get you started.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.